# How to change resolution of 2 rasters layers in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, resolution

I am working with two rasters stacks: bioclim (climate data) and soil data. They have different resolution. The description of data:

```
bioclim
#class      : RasterStack 
#dimensions : 163, 319, 51997, 19  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
#extent     : 18.83337, 72.00005, 40.99999, 68.16666  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : NA 

soil
#class      : RasterStack 
#dimensions : 1256, 2213, 2779528, 5  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 0.02259376, 0.02259376  (x, y)
#extent     : 20, 69.99999, 42.62224, 71  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : NA
```

I tried function:

```
soil <- aggregate(soil, fact=7.376669487504514)
```

I just put this number (fact), because it equals to resolution of bioclim divided by resolution of soil.

But, they have little differences:

```
res(soil)
#[1] 0.1581563 0.1581563

res(bioclim)
#[1] 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

Also I tried other functions like `aggregate`, but not successful.

I need to create main stack of two stacks: bioclim and soil. Please, could anybody help me?

```
env <- stack(bioclim,soil)
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I tried `disaggregate()` when I told about other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a self-contained, minimal, reproducible example:

```
library(raster)
bioclim <- raster(nrow=163, ncol=319, ext=extent(18.83337, 72.00005, 40.99999, 68.16666))    
soil <- raster(nrow=1256, ncol=2213, ext=extent(20, 69.99999, 42.62224, 71))
values(soil) = 1:ncell(soil)
```

Solution: if you cannot use (dis-)`aggregate`, you can use `resample`

```
sb <- resample(soil, bioclim)
sb
#class      : RasterLayer 
#dimensions : 163, 319, 51997  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution : 0.1666667, 0.1666667  (x, y)
#extent     : 18.83337, 72.00005, 40.99999, 68.16666  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : layer 
#values     : 284578.3, 2779484  (min, max)
```

Or use `terra`, if you need better performance:

```
library(terra)
bc <- rast(nrow=163, ncol=319, ext=ext(18.83337, 72.00005, 40.99999, 68.16666))
so <- rast(nrow=1256, ncol=2213, ext=ext(20, 69.99999, 42.62224, 71))
values(so) = 1:ncell(so)
  
sb <- resample(so, bc)
```